# WooCommerce Subscriptions: Discounts according to length of subscriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscription, discount

I have WooCommerce Subscriptions and [Discounts for WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/document/discounts-for-woocommerce-subscriptions/) which allows me to offer discounts according to the number of renewals.

However I can't find any plugin or method that allows me to offer the same subscription with different lengths (with discounts if the length exceeds a certain number of months).
For example:
3 months: -10%
6 months: -20%
12 months: -30%

It's currently impossible for a customer to buy multiple months of a subscription at once.

Do you know any solution ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'd be easier to just use a variable subscription?

https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/store-manager-guide/#section-6

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever found an answer to this or not but I utilized the Prepaid for Woocommerce subscriptions to solve this. A customer can buy X amount of months upfront.